# Parsing sentences using Scala parser combinator

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I just started playing with parser combinators in Scala, but got stuck on a parser to parse sentences such as "I like Scala." (words end on a whitespace or a period (`.`)).

I started with the following implementation:

```scala
package example

import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

object Example extends RegexParsers {
  override def skipWhitespace = false

  def character: Parser[String] = """\w""".r

  def word: Parser[String] =
    rep(character) <~ (whiteSpace | guard(literal("."))) ^^ (_.mkString(""))

  def sentence: Parser[List[String]] = rep(word) <~ "."
}

object Test extends App {
  val result = Example.parseAll(Example.sentence, "I like Scala.")

  println(result)
}
```

The idea behind using `guard()` is to have a period demarcate word endings, but not consume it so that sentences can. However, the parser gets stuck (adding `log()` reveals that it is repeatedly trying the `word` and `character` parser).

If I change the `word` and `sentence` definitions as follows, it parses the sentence, but the grammar description doesn't look right and will not work if I try to add parser for paragraph (`rep(sentence)`) etc.

```scala
def word: Parser[String] =
  rep(character) <~ (whiteSpace | literal(".")) ^^ (_.mkString(""))

def sentence: Parser[List[String]] = rep(word) <~ opt(".")
```

Any ideas what may be going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, the parser gets stuck (adding log() reveals that it is repeatedly trying the word and character parser).

The `rep` combinator corresponds to a `*` in perl-style regex notation. This means it matches ***zero*** or more characters. I think you want it to match ***one*** or more characters. Changing that to a `rep1` (corresponding to `+` in perl-style regex notation) should fix the problem.

However, your definition still seems a little verbose to me. Why are you parsing individual characters instead of just using `\w+` as the pattern for a word? Here's how I'd write it:

```
object Example extends RegexParsers {
  override def skipWhitespace = false

  def word: Parser[String] = """\w+""".r

  def sentence: Parser[List[String]] = rep1sep(word, whiteSpace) <~ "."
}
```

Notice that I use `rep1sep` to parse a non-empty list of words separated by whitespace. There's a `repsep` combinator as well, but I think you'd want at least one word per sentence.

Comment: Thanks. As for simplifying `word`, you are right that in the example, your solution makes more sense. The original problem I was trying to solve has a bit more complex domain, where the equivalent of `character` is a bit more complex and requires specifying its own parser.